# Derivation of formula for shortest distance between two skew lines.

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am a student of 12th standard, studying 3D Geometry currently. I am quite perplexed by the following proof regarding the formula of the shortest distance between two skew lines, I have underlined the confusing text and drawn a red rectangle over the equation that I feel is wrong (the reason why I think its wrong is because I created a 3D Model of such a figure where I made two skew lines, line representing ST, PQ(mentioned in the proof below) and the I tried to create a projection of ST on PQ in order to check whether the equation PQ = ST cos θ is correct or not, and I observed that it is not, PQ is shorter than ST cos θ , I don't know how to upload that model here so I am providing the following link https://p3d.in/bPC8K .)

HELP me understand this. Thank for you help in Advance.
[image: This is the proof given in my school textbook:]
[image]

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but the link that supposedly goes to the 3d model that you made doesn't work. It is saying "This 3d Model is not available in p3d.in".

Comment: @AidenChow Retry, I have updated the link.

Comment: That's not the projection along the shortest distance line, you have just translated it so that they coincide. After the translation, you need to take the dot product with the line of shortest distance to get the projection

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan It is written there, " the projection of ST(blue line in the model) along the direction of the line of shortest distance ( yellow line ).

Comment: Yeah, so a projection does not just mean translation, it also means you have to remove any component perpendicular to the line you are projecting on

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan dot product of two vectors is ABcos θ while the projection of a vector is Acos θ.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I didn't draw the projection there just to keep it simple, as its quite clear that the projection along the shostest distance will be greater (try to visualize a right triangle there ).

Comment: there is a typo in the final vector formula (in boldface)
$(\vec a_2 \times \vec a_1)$ should be $(\vec a_2 - \vec a_1)$

Answer (score 1):

$\theta$ mentioned here is the angle between $PQ$ and $ST$.

$PQ$ is taken as the shortest distance between the two skew lines.And then by cross product of $b_1$ and $b$, we have found out a unit vector $\hat{n}$.

$$PQ=ST\cos(\theta)$$

In this equation, we are taking projection of $ST$ vector on $PQ$ and for that we just use the $\hat{n}$ vector that we found out earlier.